# Objective C: Pretty print NSArray with different objects at each index position

Tags: nsarray, objective-c++, nslog

I have an NSArray of different objects, e.g. an NSString and an NSNumber integer.

I have a specific format string I want to use to print the object contents, not just using

```
@"%@|%@"
```

but, e.g.

```
@"%-13s|%010d"
```

I have implemented the following to do @"%@|%@" type printing that I found here on StackOverflow and elsewhere:

```
@implementation NSString (NSArrayFormatExtension)

+ (id) stringWithFormatFromNSArray: (NSString *) format array: (NSArray*) args;
{
  id *argList = malloc( sizeof( id )  * [args count] );
  [ args getObjects: argList ];

  NSString* result = [ [ [ NSString alloc ] initWithFormat: format arguments: (va_list) argList ] autorelease ];

  free(argList);

  return result; 
}

@end
```

Called and then printed like so:

```
NSString *printstring = [ NSString stringWithFormatFromNSArray: nsFormatString array: nsarray_of_objects ]
```

which will allow nsFormatStrings of type @"%@ %@" to print the object contents, but not @"%s %d" type formats to print the underlying C types with more detailed formatting.

I have two problems and some thoughts on solutions, but did not want to reinvent the wheel here.

1.) I could iterate over the NSArray items with a switch on the type derived from className - sure - but I wondered if there was a standard way to do this.

It would also mean deconstructing the format string into individual % entities (or passing *it* in as an array and working through it - not very clean, as well as needing to preserving any other non-formatting entries, like the pipe-delimiter above).

2.) The above code using @"%@|%@" works as-is on 32-bit Linux with gcc / objc / objc++ 4.6.X and above but segfaults on 64-bit Linux and I need to have it working on both.

From what I've read, this appears to be a fairly general problem with the 64-bit implementation of va_list on some Linux systems.

Even if I was content with the object formatting, vs. specific C type formatting, this is still broken. Does anyone have a fix for this? It would seem that it would tend to force implementing solution 1.) to be portable in every instance, but that's

a.) time-consuming to code and 
b.) not efficient.

I really need to be able to do the detailed formatting as well as the results from printing this from a command line program would need to be read by a completely different system as a CSV file or from a pipeline or the like.

It's possible I may want to use different delimiters between fields as well - e.g.

```
....|....;....,....#....^....
```

which I would embed in my format string just fine if I could do it that way.

So, any formatting with a single "joining" separator isn't the answer either.

Soooooo much easier to do this kind of thing in Perl ;-) - but - this particular piece of software is being written in Objc++ (linking with a C++ lib).

Your thoughts and suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Your 1st point looks good. Why you dont want to go that way?

Comment: It's seeming like the only realistic option. Just a lot of heavy lifting to do something reasonably "simple" - like, formatted printing of a varied array. In Perl: `printf "%-13s|%010d\n", @array;` where `@array` can contain varied types - yes, not objects, but converting from objects to primitive types would be easier inline too, e.g. `printf "%-13s|%010d\n", $array[0]->getstring, $array[1]->getnum;`. Surprised this isn't done more often in ObjC, but I guess people rely upon "description" or @"%@" or probably more likely are not writing Linux CLI Objc code as much as for iPhone/iPad/MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your program does not work on some platforms is that it uses non-portable behavior - casting a C-style array of `id`s to `va_list` is not guaranteed to work:

```
(va_list) argList
```

That is also the reason why the formatting of the primitives, along the `%010d` lines, does not work: `NSArray` cannot contain primitives, so an `int` is represented by `NSNumber` with an `int` inside.

In general, C (and by extension, Objective C) do not support dynamic creation of variable-argument lists. That is why you cannot use the formatting methods that require variable argument lists.

Unfortunately, your best option requires a lot of coding. Make a method like this:

```
+ (id) stringWithFormatsFromNSArray: (NSArray*) formats array: (NSArray*) args {
    // verify that formats and args have the same number of entries
    NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int i = 0 ; i != args.count ; i++) {
        id arg = [args objectAtIndex:i];
        id fmt = [formats objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([arg isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            // Apply fmt to NSNumberFormatter
            NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            [nf setFormat:fmt];
            [res appendString:[nf stringFromNumber:arg]];
        } else {
            [res appendFormat:fmt, arg];
        }
    }
    return [res copy];
}
```

This code assumes that the first argument is an array, not a string. Each element must contain the format for the corresponding argument. Formats for numbers will be passed to `NSNumberFormatter`, which lets you format non-primitive objects that represent numbers. All other formats will be passed to `appendFormat`. Note that separators must be included with the format string of the corresponding object. It is up to you to add separators in front of all objects except the initial one, or after all objects except the trailing one.

Comment: Appr. the sugg. I'll mod & try it. The known prob. with Linux gcc 64bit va_list behavior is troubling. I've tried various ways of initializing the byte sequence; I only showed one in my e.g. I'll see if I can post the va_list links I saw as well. Your partial solution above mirrors the thinking I proposed, but requires a lot of code as you say to handle all possible % codes that I am interested in supporting, and handling non-% sep & other chars. Messy however it's done. Want to pass in format strings if I can, not an array as I said. I understand the need to convert Obj to primitive types.